# Xcode 7 beta 3 crash at startup

Tags: xcode, crash-reports, xcode7-beta3

I have a problem after XCode7 beta 3 installation: is not possible for me to use Xcode because every time it crash at startup! I have only the crash report but I don't understand where is the problem. My Xcode 6.4 works without problem. Can someone help me? Here the first line of crash report...

```
Process:               Xcode [1012]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.0 (8163.8)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8163008000000000~7
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1012]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-07-11 09:37:48.062 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        9AE5A2B5-E5A8-37F4-E7B7-C9E99A3CB864

Sleep/Wake UUID:       60DC0ED0-51DA-4158-B5FF-F5B35B44D0A4

Time Awake Since Boot: 9200 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: IDESourceControlTree Change Queue

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A152u
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8163.8/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlTree.m:82
Details:  (location) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDESourceControlRepository: 0x7fcdf0385930>
Method:   -_initWithLocation:sourceControlManager:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fcdebf0a540>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
```

Comment: Do you have any 3rd-party plugins installed?

Comment: No I don't have 3rd-party plugins but after some work I find a solution and now I can run Xcode 7 look at my reply. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

After seeing a suggestion [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8818), I solved this issue by deleting Xcode's preferences. The most reliable way to do that is the following terminal command, issued after quitting Xcode:

`defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

ETA: Other suggestions have involved changing or removing certain individual preference settings, but after trying a few of those, none worked for me. There seem to be multiple incompatibilities in the preferences between 6 and 7b3, so trashing the prefs entirely should work around them all.

Comment: This worked for me. Now I can use Xcode 7 beta 3. Yay!

Comment: The only solution that works after trying everything!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me by doing the following: in the previous version of Xcode(6.4) Preferences > Accounts and delete all the repositories entries. Xcode 7 stopped crashing.

Comment: This is the right answer, apparently the older xcode doesn't mind having invalid repos, but the new one does.

Answer (score 2):

For me deleting some plugins off of [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io) did the job.

Alcatraz is a plugin manager for Xcode and you can access the list of installed plugins by hitting `⌘ ⇧ 9` and then selecting `Installed` from the top bar.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

To solve my issue, I have done this:

- I opened Xcode 6.4 (the current Xcode)
- Opened Preferences
- From preferences selected the Location tab
- In derived data I selected "relative" instead of "absolute"
- After this, I can run Xcode 7.
- I restore the same setting as before and all works again

It's very strange, it appears to be a settings error.

Comment: Why the down vote? Probably there are different solution but is not correct to vote down. In my case I solved the problem!

Comment: You are right. But vote is now locked. If you edit that I would clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Crash caused by embedding frameworks or linking libraries can be sorted by

```
app.xcodeproj -> right click -> show package contents -> open project.pbxproj in text editor
```

and search and replace the lines containing the newly added framework names.

Then add it again properly once xcode opened successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while upgrading from xcode7.2 to 7.3. Everything was fine except the conflicting PLUGINs.

Try removing plugins you might have installed in xcode and it will work. In my case Alcatraz plugin was the culprit. Just removed it from the path /Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode and all went good.

P.S : Make sure your mac OS is compatible with the xcode you are installing!! sometimes blindly installing xcode without upgrading OS (like I was doing ;) ) can cause such hazardous behaviour. Best Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get it work

first I used the tips of this [link](https://developerinsider.co/clean-xcode-cache-quick-fix/) combining other answers

so in command line:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

from the this [link](https://gist.github.com/vineetchoudhary/b09c3f40ca29d36c8863#file-fix-xcode-rb) to the ruby file

```
ruby xcode-fix.rb
```